# Resampling pandas dataframe and putting the results in columns, with the day as the index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, shapes

I have a dataset with power every 30 minutes.

It has a timestamp as the index in the format 2016-06-01 00:00:00 
2016-06-01 00:00:00 etc.

I can group the data using `df.groupby(pf.TimeGrouper(freq='D'))`
but I then want the contents of the group to be placed in columns 1-48, so each line of the resulting dataset has a day on the left and 48 power entries to the right.

Original data

`2016-06-01 00:00:00     5

2016-06-01 00:30:00     9

2016-06-01 01:00:00     12`

Goal

`DATETIME     00:00:00     00:30:00     01:00:00

2016-06-01       5            9            12`

I'm sure there must be a rule I can use to add to the end of the timegrouper line that for example makes a list out of all the values and transposes them onto one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example data:

```
import pandas as pd

times = ["2016-06-01 00:00:00", "2016-06-01 00:30:00", "2016-06-01 01:00:00"]
vals = [5, 9, 12]
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(time = times, value = vals))
```

Split time into date and time:

```
df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df.time)
df["date"] = df.time.dt.date
df["time"] = df.time.dt.time

       time  value        date
0  00:00:00      5  2016-06-01
1  00:30:00      9  2016-06-01
2  01:00:00     12  2016-06-01
```

Then pivot the data:

```
df.pivot(index="date", columns="time", values="value")

time        00:00:00  00:30:00  01:00:00
date                                
2016-06-01         5         9        12
```

Answer (score 1):

You could

```
In [881]: df.set_index([df.time.dt.date, df.time.dt.time])['value'].unstack()
Out[881]:
time        00:00:00  00:30:00  01:00:00
time
2016-06-01         5         9        12
```

To rename axis

```
In [903]: (df.set_index([df.time.dt.date, df.time.dt.time])['value'].unstack()
             .rename_axis(None).rename_axis('DATETIME', 1))
Out[903]:
DATETIME    00:00:00  00:30:00  01:00:00
2016-06-01         5         9        12
```

Or, instead of `set_index` use `groupby`

```
In [907]: df.groupby([df.time.dt.date, df.time.dt.time])['value'].sum().unstack()
Out[907]:
time        00:00:00  00:30:00  01:00:00
time
2016-06-01         5         9        12
```